# Voice and face recognition libraries for .Net Gadgeteer

Tags: voice-recognition, robotics, face-recognition, .net-micro-framework, .net-gadgeteer

Recently, I've been looking into robotics and I've become interested in trying to make a robot of my own. It woulde be a simple one but I want it to be capable of face and speech recognition at least.

I've found a set called EZ-Robots that comes with face/speech recognition libraries already, but thought that .NET gadgeteer would be better (more simple, scalable...). So far, I haven't tried any programming yet, I still need to decide which set to buy (which way to go).

I am an experienced programmer, but absolute beginner in harware stuff.

My vision is that I focus mostly on software and build only basic, simple hardware. I want to interact with robot so he must recognize me (or at least tell human from other objects). I would like to speak to it, give it command etc. I live in Czech Repubic and there isn't much software available for voice recognition in my language. If I could record a command and he would recognize it, that's enough.

It is more of a hobby matter :).

For any advice, I would be grateful.